# Permanent removal of logo in Windows Scripting Host (WSH) scripts

Tags: vbscript, wsh, windows-scripting, windows-console

I know two ways to remove the logo permanently. The "official" one:

```
cscript //Nologo //S
```

Will save current command line options for current user.

A `ftype` approach with admin privileges:

```
ftype wsffile="%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "%%1" %%*
ftype  jsfile="%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "%%1" %%*  
ftype vbsfile="%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "%%1" %%*
```

Double-`%`'s are needed only if you use the lines in a batch file.

The latter will all users via affect the reg key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file>\Shell\Open\Command`, where `<file>` can be `wsffile`, `jsfile` or `vbsfile`.

Do you know where are stored the  `cscript //Nologo //S` settings?

Comment: +1 for being the first place I've found pointing me to `/nologo /s` to save the option (due to completely missing it on the options listed using `/?`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logo settings are saved in the DWORD value `DisplayLogo` the subkey `Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings` under both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (`HKEY_USERS\<SID>`, actually).

To change the default setting for all users set the value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to `0x0`:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings" /v DisplayLogo /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0 /f
```

To change the setting for the current user set the value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to `0x0`:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings" /v DisplayLogo /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0 /f
```

If you want to modify the settings for other users, you'll have to load their user hive into the registry first.